# Inserting/formatting in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

I have created a table and bulk inserted a file that is all in 'Column0' right now.

The file format is like this:

```
#text1 "123123" 20180305 "text 123"
{
    #num2  xxxxxx 123.12 20180101
    #num3  yyyyyy 321.32 20180102
    #num3  zzzzzz 111.11 20180103
}
#text2 "332132" 20180203 "text 433"
{
    #num8  jjjjjj 222.22 20180104
    #num4  uuuuuu 11.23 20180204
}

...
```

And so on. What I want to do is to make a query to format this to be something like

```
numNr    numAmount    numDate    textNr   
xxxxxx   123.12       20180101   123123    
yyyyyy   321.32       20180102   123123
zzzzzz   111.11       20180103   123123
jjjjjj   222.22       20180104   332132
uuuuuu   11.23        20180204   332132
```

In other words, I want to tie the number in #text1 to all the rows between the {} after it, and then when I hit another textnumber like #text2 I want this text number to be tied to the rows following this number and so on. Kind of hard to explain but hopefully you get it, otherwise let me know and I will try to explain further.

How could this be done?

UPDATE:
I just bulk inserted the data and since it was formatted this way everything is in column0 which is Column0 varchar(max).

The problem that I can't solve from the other thread is that I wan't to kind of loop through all rows and at the first row where I find a line beginning with #text1, I want to add the number  next to it, in this case "123123" to a new table with

```
textNumber    ID
123123        1
```

Then I want all numbers inside {} to have the same ID, so for example another table with

```
numNumber    amount    date       ID
xxxxxx       123.12    20180101   1
```

And then the plan is to join these to so I get the result

```
numNumber    amount    date       ID    textNumber
xxxxxx       123.12    20180101   1     123123
```

So in programming langugage I would like to loop through each row of the table and set the ID = 1 and add this to a new column when the loop hit a row where left(Column0, 5) = '#text'. After that I want this ID to be added to all following rows beginning with left(Column0, 8) = '    #num'.

After this, when I hit another row beginning with left(Column0, 5) = '#text', I want the ID to be updated to ID = 2, and then this new ID will be added to the following rows beginning with left(Column0, 8) = '    #num'.

And so on.... But from what I understand, the looping part is not very good in SQL...

Does this make sense? How could I do this the easiest way?

Comment: The link above appears to be an exact duplicate of your question.  The trick you may use is to add an extra computed column to the table which maintains the name of the file source.

Comment: How did u managed to insert in that format and what is datatype and length of single column